# Multiplying over Subtraction

Tags: arithmetic, factoring

I'd like to take maths seriously but I'm not that great at it, so I decided to learn at home. I know this is pretty basic, but as I said, I'm pretty bad at maths, haha.

The worksheet gives me this example:

> $7 (9o + 7) = 63o + 49$

I completed this one myself:

> $5 (3l + 7) = 15l + 21$

My question is, what do I do if the plus operator is replaced with substraction?

Example:

> $-3 (6w - 2)$

Here's what I got, although I doubt it's correct: $-18 w -  -1.5$

---

Thanks kindly for your help!

Comment: It is far better to type $-18 w - (-1.5)$ than $-18 w - \, -1.5$ (`-18 w - -1.5`), because this last one is not a standard notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $\;a,\,b\,:\;\;\; a - b = a + (-b).\;\;$

So for your last example, we can proceed as follows:

$$-3(6w - 2)\, = \,-3\,[\,6w + (-2)\,]\, =\,(-3)(6w) + (-3)(-2)\, = \,-18w +  6$$

Answer (score 2):

It's same, $-3(6w - 2) = (-3)(6w) + (-3)(-2) = -18w + 6$